# How to add server classes for all contexts in Jetty?

Tags: servlets, jetty, slf4j, logback

I have jetty configured to use slf4j and logback. version 8.x

According to this place http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/jetty-users/msg02859.html you can add those classes in the list of server classes of jetty per context, so the web application can't see the slf4j server classes.

I don't want to do this for each war I deploy. Is it possible to configure only once all the classes AND resources ($JETTY_HOME/resources/logback.xml is visible to webapps by default) of the server that are not to be available in the classloader of deployed webapps ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can have a class that participates in the [deployment lifecycle of webapps](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-8/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/deploy/AppLifeCycle.html).

Example Class:

```
package example.deploy.logging.config;

import org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.App;
import org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.AppLifeCycle;
import org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.graph.Node;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler;
import org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext;

public class LoggingConfigBinding implements AppLifeCycle.Binding
{
    public String[] getBindingTargets()
    {
        return new String[]
        { "deploying" };
    }

    public void processBinding(Node node, App app) throws Exception
    {
        ContextHandler handler = app.getContextHandler();
        if (handler == null)
        {
            throw new NullPointerException("No Handler created for App: " + app);
        }

        if (handler instanceof WebAppContext)
        {
            WebAppContext webapp = (WebAppContext)handler;
            webapp.addSystemClass("org.slf4j.");
        }
    }
}
```

Then you'll have a piece of XML that loads it into the [DeploymentManager](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-8/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/deploy/DeploymentManager.html)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Jetty//Configure//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure.dtd">
<Configure id="Server" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server">
  <Ref id="DeploymentManager">
    <Call name="addLifeCycleBinding">
      <Arg>
        <New class="example.deploy.logging.config.LoggingConfigBinding">
        </New>
      </Arg>
    </Call>
  </Ref>
</Configure>
```

For a more complete example see [Sifting Logs in Logback on Jetty](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Tutorial/Sifting_Logs_with_Logback) (note: logback is a slf4j logging implementation).

Comment: The "Sifting Logs in Logback on Jetty" reference in the answer has links to all of the various full projects on git.codehaus.org and github.  Be sure to read that.  For a real-world example of that codebase, look at this project: http://git.codehaus.org/gitweb.cgi?p=jetty-project.git;a=tree;f=jetty-webapp-logging

Comment: I read "Sifting Logs in Logback on Jetty" but I really need to isolate the logging of each web application at the classloader level.

Comment: Thank you!, Your solution does work. Now I am confirming that the webapp is using the $JETTY_HOME/resources/logback.xml and not the webapp.war[WEB-INF/classes/logback.xml] Can I deal with the logback.xml file the same way I deal with class packages in LoggingConfigBinding ?